# Are there limits on the number of unique polygons created by the QGIS Union tool?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, union

Is there a limit on the number of polygons that the Union tool will compute? I have overlapping radii from a variety of sources pictured below, but the tool continues to give me an "GEOS geoprocessing error: intersection failed" error every time I try with a larger dataset.

I've tried to fix geometries and checked validities for topology, are my overlaps just too numerous so the tool fails? Is there anything I can try, other than splitting my data into smaller and smaller peices and Unioning them individually until I get my final solution?

[image: Threat radius overlaps at 16.5 percent opacity]

Comment: I suggest you provide us with the exact input settings when you run the tool.

Comment: What settings are useful to add? The only input into the tool that I use is the single buffered layer to Union over itself.

Comment: Well, what happens when you don't set an overlay?

Comment: Ah, the error occured when I didn't set an overlay, but when I set the same layer as the overlay I end up with an output. Thanks very much, but I'm afraid I'll run into some data errors now, as things have been duplicated which is what I was trying to avoid by running it singly, as opposed to overlaying itself.

Comment: I did try to reproduce it and when I didn't set an overlay layer (the tool mark it as optional) I also get an error whit lot of feature but it work for just two feature. If I input the same layer both as input and overlay the union tool work with all the feature but I get everything as duplicate...